# XtraReports Page break if content doesn't fit?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a report that populates multiple rows of data per section, and multiple sections per report.

When I generate the report, the data fills out the page but gets cut in half at the bottom and continues onto the next page.

I've tried adding a page break in the properties, yet it seems the only options allow for me to page break after one section which leaves a lot of blank space on the remainder of the page.

All I want is for my data to not get cut off, so is there a way to adjust the page break this way?

Thanks

Comment: Is all of your data being printed on the detail band?

Comment: Do you mind sending a screen shot of the report designer?